# MYSQL optimized primary key query change

Tags: php, mysql

I'm hoping there is a faster way to do this as this query takes forever to run. And I'm hoping to learn something at the same time.

I have two tables from two separate databases. I need to merge the ids. Because the 2nd database has multiple tables that reference the id, I have to change all those first

I added the number 9696 in front of the id since none of the id's start with 9xxx. 
So the first query goes in and changes all the ids but puts 9696 in front to prevent any cross id change. And the second one removes all the 9696 from the id's so we get the original id.

There are over a dozen other tables that I am doing this for.. but I feel there has to be a better way. Maybe there isn't a better way.. But I had to ask .. I've tried search to see if I could find but all I found was how to change the primary key. Not a better way to change all references. Is there really a better way to do this?

```
$userResult = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE forum_id!='0' AND forum_id != id");
while ($userRow = $userResult->fetch_assoc()){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE operation SET member_id='9696".$userRow['forum_id']."' WHERE member_id='".$userRow['id']."'");
}
$mysqli->query("UPDATE operation SET leader=REPLACE(leader, '9696', '') WHERE leader LIKE '9696%'");
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "merge the ids", and I don't understand whey you're adding prefixes then removing them. Perhaps you can explain further.

Comment: The prefix was to prevent cross id.. Some of the id's are the same. so if I did a straight convert this number, and it had already been changed before I would be altering that data again. Thus the prefix to prevent changing something that has already been changed.

Comment: So, you don't care to explain what the problem is to get better solutions, you just want to speed up your current solution? You'll need to provide more information still, like full schema (including indexes and data types).

Comment: There are no index's the database is too small. However you are right. I should have mentioned that the id's were INT(11). I knew there had to be a faster way as this query takes over 40min to do. And it should only be a few minutes.

Comment: If it's taking 40 minutes, then it's not too small for indexes. Add indexes on operation(member_id), operation(leader), and members(forum_id) to really see the performance of your queries improve. Still, there may be better ways to "merge ids", though we have no idea what that is since we have no idea what "merge ids" means.

Comment: We have a forum with member id's ranging from 0 to 8,000. We have a custom application which was written before we were using forums that also has member id's with the same range. Obviously they do not match up. We're trying to make it so the custom application uses the same ids as the forum so that information can easily be grabbed from the forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this way more efficiently with a multi-table update query and arithmetic rather than string operations, like so:

```
UPDATE
  members m join
  operation o on
     m.id = o.member_id

  SET o.member_id= m.forum_id + 10000

WHERE m.forum_id !=0 AND m.forum_id != id;

UPDATE operation SET leader=leader-10000 WHERE leader > 1000;
```

This assumes that member_id and forum_id are numerical, and that your largest id value is under 10,000 (if not then just increase the amount you add and subtract accordingly).

If you have to do it using single tables, via mysqli, then this at least might be better:

```
$userResult = $mysqli->query("SELECT forum_id, id FROM members WHERE forum_id!='0' AND forum_id != id");
while ($userRow = $userResult->fetch_assoc()){
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE operation SET member_id=".$userRow['forum_id']."+10000' WHERE member_id='".$userRow['id']."'");
}
$mysqli->query("UPDATE operation SET leader=leader-10000 WHERE leader > 10000");
```

Note that only retrieving  the fields you need from the first select will give you a small performance enhancement.

Comment: You'll have to be careful not to hit any numeric type max with this approach.

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue if the largest ids are under 9000 (As implied in the question)

Comment: Ok. So concatenating is slower than just adding I get it. makes sense. I wouldn't have thought to just add 10k to the value. The replace was the only way I knew how to do it. I thought I was being "clever". I knew there had to be a faster way. I also got to learn something. Thank you.

Comment: My pleasure, glad it helped. Out of interest, if your original version took 40 mins, how long does it take now?

Comment: Simon, its under 5 minutes now.